# Random Variable $X= U:(0,4)$ is given. Find the CDF of $\min \{ |X-1|, 5-X\}+1$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

Random Variable $X= U:(0,4)$ is given. Find the CDF of $Y=\min \{ |X-1|, 5-X\}+1$

X has uniform distribution. So we know that $$Y\in (1,6)$$, therefore

$$y\leq 1 \ \ \ F_y(y)=0 ; y\geq6\ \ \  F_y(y)=1$$  I start it off like this:
$$F_y(y)=P\{Y<y\}=\{\ \ \ \min \{ |X-1|, 5-X\} < y+1\ \ \ \}$$
$$=1-\{\ \ \ \min \{ |X-1|, 5-X\}+1 > y+1\ \ \ \}$$
$$=1- P\{ |X-1|-1>y,\ \ \ \  4-x\geq y\ \} $$

Now what is confusing me is the following: Do I draw this area and take into consideration the *valid* areas, meaning I integrate the area between the above two functions and add the bounderies y=6 and y=1? And is the PDF when integrating $ {1 \over 4 }?$ I would appreciate an answer within today.

Comment: Makes it somewhat harder, still pretty accessible. Forget about the outer $+{}1$ part, it can be dealt with at the end. Let $Z$ be the minimum of $|X-1|$ and $5-X$. We want $\Pr(Z\le z)$. The answer will have different form depending on the value of $z$. For example if $z\le 1$ we want the probability that $X$ is between $1-z$ and $1+z$. This probability is $\frac{2z}{4}$.

Comment: Could you maybe type out a complete answer, I would very much appreciate it. The professor today said that I should draw the functions |X-1|, 5-X then identify the min within (0,1) and translate that 1 up, what I have trouble is identifying the minimum within that interval, what does that actually mean ?

Comment: I am not sure I will have the time today, and unfortunately the good intuitive solution does involve drawing pictures, which would take much too long to draw using software and post. Will "favourite" the question and get to it when I have the time.

Comment: What if I were to post the drawings of the functions here, ask you for updates where  to draw next and what to integrate and why, that is if you have time for this? My exam is tomorrow, so I am more diligent then normal. :) I'll draw |X-1| and 5-X for starters if you agree. :)

Comment: If you have drawn them and are sure you did it correctly, there is no need. Because of the exam, I will try to post fairly soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=\min(|X-1|, 5-X)$. We find the cdf of $W$. The cdf of $Y$ can then be obtained easily by pushing everything forward by $1$.  Apologies for the length. I wanted to put in lots of detail, and do not have time to tighten things up.

Draw carefully the curves $y=|x-1|$ and $y=5-x$. Everything depends on that.

Note that $y=|x-1$ is $y=1-x$ to the left of $x=1$, and is $y=x-1$ to the right of $x=1$.

Note that the $y=x-1$ part meets $y=5-x$ at $x=3$.  For $0\le x\lt 3$, the curve $y=|x-1|$ is **below** $y=5-x$. After that, it is above. So $\min(|x-1|, 5-x)=|x-1|$ for $0\le x\lt 3$, and $\min(|x-1|,5-x)=5-x$ for $x\ge 3$. Actually, we are only interested in $x$ up to $4$.

Now we have everything needed to find the cdf of $W$. Recall that the cdf $F_W(w)$ is $\Pr(W\le w)$. And lest I forget, note the trivial facts that $F_W(w)=0$ if $w\lt 0$. Note also, from the diagram, that $\min(|x-1|,5-x)\le 2$ in our interval. So $F_W(w)=1$ for $w\gt 2$.

It remains to find the cdf in the interesting part, from $w=0$ to $w=2$.

First we deal with $0\le w\le 1$. Then $W\le w$ if and only if $X$ is between $1-w$ and $1+w$. This interval has width $2w$, and our density function is $\frac{1}{4}$. So $\Pr(1-w\le X\le 1+w)=\frac{2w}{4}$. We conclude that $F_w(w)=\frac{2w}{4}$ for $0\le w\le 1$.

Finally, we deal with the hardest part, $1\le w\lt 2$. For such $w$, the event $W\le w$ can happen  in $3$ ways.

(i) It could be that $|X-1|\le 1$, that is, $X\le 2$. This has probability $\frac{2}{4}$.

(ii) It could be that $2\lt X \le 1+w$. This has probability $\frac{w+1-2}{4}$, which is $\frac{w-1}{4}$.

(iii) It could we that $X$ is between $3$ and $4$ but "near" $4$, so that $5-X\le w$. that gives $5-w\le X\le 4$, which has probability $\frac{4-(5-w)}{4}$, which is \frac{w-1}{4}$.

Adding up, we find that if $1\lt w\le 2$ we have $\Pr(W\le w)=\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2(w-1)}{4}$, which simplifies to $\frac{2w}{4}$.

If you really wanted to use integrals, then for (ii) we would use $\int_2^{w+1}\frac{dx}{4}$. But we are calculating areas of rectangles, so integration seems like overkill.

Small reality check: The value of $F_W(w)$ at $w=2$ should be $1$. Our calculation gives $F_W(w)=\frac{2w}{4}$ in this interval, and this is indeed $1$ at $w=2$.

Comment: shouldn't ii) be $\int_{2}^{w-1}{dx\over 4}={w-3 \over 4 }$ if you integrate like that??

Comment: Thank you for spotting it. I also fixed a typo, others may remain. In terms of integrals, it is $\int_2^{1+w} \frac{dx}{4}$.

Comment: Now I am confused as to how to integrate these, I thought I had it down, do I go from left to right with the bounderies, it seems like it should be the typo intuitively

Comment: We want $X-1\le w$, so $X\le w+1$.  I mentioned the integration way in one of the parts because in the case the density function was not constant, we really would need to integrate,

Comment: I see now, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. In terms of integration, the shape of the upper limit changes, and it is useful to break up the integral into parts.